# What is a word equivalent to "bias" without the meaning where it is considered to be unfair?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is a word equivalent to "bias" without the meaning where it is considered to be unfair?

From a google search the meaining of bias is:

> an inclination or prejudice for or against one person or group,
> especially in a way considered to be unfair.

I am looking for word that means an inclination for or against one person or group (without the consideration of it being unfair or fair). Like preference of some sought but also like almost a synonym to bias.

Is there such a word?

Comment: I doubt if such a word exists. You could look up _partisanship_, _tendentiousness_, _predisposition_, and related words to see if they fit. You might also want to add a sample sentence to making things clearer.

Comment: Single word requests require an example sentence using the word. Context is all. Does “Gentlemen prefer Blondes” indicate unfair treatment of brunettes?

Comment: If you search the site for [bias](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=bias) there are a lot of questions on the topic, none exactly the same as yours but many similar which use other terms. user405662 gives a useful list above that you can enter in a thesaurus.

Comment: *to make things clearer.* Sorry about the typo.

Comment: Preference for? Taste for? Yen for? Aversion to? Dislike of?